# ColdFusion won't display query results when they are 0

Tags: coldfusion

I've written a report using ColdFusion and SQL, and the queries won't return any rows when a certain value in every row is zero. I'm using a cfstoredproc to retrieve the data, and this is how I'm displaying it:

```
    <cfloop query="DONORS_WITHDRAWN">
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><cfoutput>#DONORS_WITHDRAWN.Reason#</cfoutput></td>
            <td align="right" style="padding-right: 58px"><cfoutput>#DONORS_WITHDRAWN.Number_of_DONOR_withdrawals#</cfoutput></td>              
        </tr>
    </cfloop>
```

This is how the results look when only some of the values are zero:
[image]

And this is how they look when all of the results are zero (no rows are displayed):
[image]

When I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio for a time period when all of the results are zero, all of the rows are returned as expected. They just won't appear in the ColdFusion report unless at least one of the values is greater than zero.

Comment: What do your `donors_withdrawn` sproc call and the code inside it look like? Before your query results loop, do a `cfdump` of it to see what it actually looks like. And is your stored procedure returning output results?

Comment: And are you using `cfquery` to `EXEC` your stored procedure rather than using `cfstoredproc`? If so, don't do it that way. Use `cfstoredproc` instead.

Comment: I just changed some things around in the SQL query and I think it's working correctly now (All zero results will show now, I just have to make sure it's getting the correct data). Earlier the stored procedure was returning output results, but I may have been giving it slightly different input parameters when I was running the ColdFusion report which was causing the stored proc to not return any results. Thanks for the tip on cfdump, I'll try that if I run into more trouble.

Comment: you should write up and answer that shows the before and after so that others can benefit from what you discovered

Comment: You're right I should, I'll do that next time I'm at my computer.